# Why is my function returning error message: 'wordlist is not defined

Tags: python, function

When running this program I get this error message: NameError: name 'wordList' is not defined. Can't figure out why. Thanks.

import random

def main():

```
def getRandomWord(wordList):
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) -1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

words = "Harry John Paul Jane Sue Frank Julie Tom Alice Sam".split()

secretWord = getRandomWord(words)



print("Welcome to You Bet Your Life with Groucho\n")
print("Say the secret word and win a thousand dollars!")

your_word = input("What is your guess for the secret word? ")



if your_word == secretWord:
    print("Congratulations you are correct. The secrt word is", secretWord)
    print("and you win $1000 dollars !")
else:
    print("Sorry, that is not the secret word.")

playAgain = True
wordList = secretWord
playAgain = input("Do you want to play again? (yes or y) to continue")

if playAgain == "Yes" or playAgain == "y":
    getRandomWord(wordList)
else:
    print("Ok. Goodbye.")
```

if **name** == '**main**': main()

Comment: `wordlist` is not `wordList`. Python is case sensitive.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: On the side note, `main()` should be actually `if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`

Comment: Thanks Aran and mad! I made the corrections but program ends if I answer y or n as to playing again. getRandomWord(wordList) is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seen you were having trouble with getting to your game to start over. Simply calling your function will not restart the entire game or bring you back to the top but a small adjustment you can make is to put everything into a `while` loop with a condition like so

```
play = 'y'
while play == 'y':

    words = "Harry John Paul Jane Sue Frank Julie Tom Alice Sam".split()
    ....

    playAgain = input("Do you want to play again? (yes or y) to continue")

    if playAgain == "Yes" or playAgain == "y":
        play = 'y'
        continue
    else:
        print("Ok. Goodbye.")
        play = 'n'
```

All this does is that if `play`'s value is `y` the game will replay until the value is changed to `n` then the loop will end and so the game

Comment: Thanks vash for your help and Patrick for the debug article !